# why its going in infinite loop?

Tags: c++, file

I have a class that takes a html file and formats it. Here is my code.

```
void FormatHtml::Format(const std::string &formattedFile, const std::string &inputFile) const
{
    string str;
    ifstream inputfileObj(inputFile.c_str());
    //ofstream formattedFileObj(formattedFile.c_str());

    if(inputfileObj.is_open() /*&& formattedFileObj.is_open()*/)
    {
        while(inputfileObj.good())
        {
            getline(inputfileObj,str);
            //cout<<str<<endl;
            //formattedFileObj<<str;
            int pos = str.find(">");
            int pos3;
            while(pos != string::npos)
            {
                pos3 = str.find("<",pos);
                if(str.length() >= pos3+1) 
                {
                    if(str.at(pos3+1) == '/')
                    {
                        pos = str.find(">",pos3);
                    }
                }
                cout<<str.substr(0,pos+1)<<endl;
                //formattedFileObj<<str.substr(0,pos+1)<<endl;

                str = str.substr(pos+1,string::npos);
                pos = str.find(">");
            }
        }

        inputfileObj.close();
        //formattedFileObj.close();
    }
    else
        cout<<"could not open file";
}
```

}

but if i use this function with small file it works fyn, but for larger html file like google's  home page source it goes to infinite loop.

following is call stack.

```
ntdll.dll!76f99a94()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!76f98d94()    
ntdll.dll!76fa9522()    
kernel32.dll!7588cb6c()     
kernel32.dll!7588cbfc()     
kernel32.dll!7588c964()
```

> msvcr90d.dll!_write_nolock(int fh=14548992, const void * buf=0x77004cc0, unsigned int cnt=4074376)  Line 335 + 0x3c bytes   C
>       ffffffff()

And when i pause the execution it always stops in one file called write.c and at following code:

```
                /* write the lf buf and update total */
                if ( WriteFile( (HANDLE)_osfhnd(fh),
                            lfbuf,
                            (int)(q - lfbuf),
                            (LPDWORD)&written,
                            NULL) )
                {
                    charcount += written;
                    if (written < q - lfbuf)
                        break;
                }
```

Any one having clue what could be the reason, why it always happens with large unformatted file.

Comment: I'm willing to bet this happens when written == 0 and `q==lbuf`

Comment: `pos = str.find(">");` starts at the beginning of the `string` again, you probably want to continue searching from where you've got up to.

Comment: yes peter... my logic goes that way only

Comment: this the value for autos sehe
+  &written 0x7ffdcff0 int *
  fh 3866624 int
+  lfbuf 0x7ffdbbb0 <Bad Ptr> char [5120]

Comment: I would suggest starting it up in the debugger, and once it appears to be looping indefinitely, (probably fairly soon) pausing it.  Now work your way through an iteration, noting the values of key variables.  You have expectations of things changing from one iteration of the loop to the next.  See what expectation is violated and why.

Comment: @DRVic Or extract the loop body to a separate function and test in a unit test harness, making expectations explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
pos = str.find(">",pos3);
```

If pos == string::npos, then you carry on to do this:

```
str = str.substr(pos+1,string::npos);
pos = str.find(">");
```

string::npos == -1, so pos+1 == 0, so str.substr returns all of str.  You are now in an infinite loop.